# Python pyinstaller converted code to .exe repeat every hour

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, repeat

I want to repeat my program every hour. But without using the windows task scheduler. I use tkinter and python 3.4 .  I tried it with

```
schedule.every(2).minutes.do(main)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

but after the second repeat i have problems with the mainloop. So is there a way to pack this in my program and then  use simple my .exe file.

Comment: Does your program automatically exit mainloop when it's done?

Comment: no i think that is my problem  because  at the second loop my program stuck at a certain point.

Comment: i forgot to say that i use destroy to quit the tkinter.. and if i use the windows task scheduler it works .

Comment: If it is stuck "at a certain point", what is that point?

Comment: ok also i am trying to write a mini project to learn tkinter better. i create a root with buttons and an entryfield. i have a pack my tkinter root in a class. Than i have outside a if elif, method . So the point where i stuck is if i run the code the first time ,there is no problem, but at the second time its stuck on my if else methode . the gui open again but i can not get the messega on the if elif method.

Comment: i can also edit my code if it is helpful?